# What are the rules on semi-colons?

Tags: semicolons

> Cruise ships can stay in one port for a short time only; which can be a problem if one wants to stay longer.

Can I use a semi-colon in this sentence of two halves?

Comment: A comma would do just as well.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Proofreading is out of scope for us. The semicolon signals an independent clause (that is, it could stand alone as its own sentence). But your sentence after the semicolon is a dependent clause (that is, it depends on the previous part and does not stand alone). Therefore, you should replace the semicolon with a comma.

Comment: This is a very old-fashioned usage, probably best avoided. It is essentially equivalent to sentence + sentence fragment << Cruise ships can stay in one port for a short time only. Which can be a problem if one wants to stay longer. >> This would nowadays be considered fine, punchy in a modern novel, but off-register with serious writing. A comma or a dash (the latter implying a thoughtful, emphasising pause in speech) are better. // Replacing 'which' by 'this', which gives you two independent clauses, and retaining the semicolon or using two sentences, also works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The phrase "of which"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385276/the-phrase-of-which) Essentially the same question, but with 'the branches of which' in place of 'which'.

Comment: Semicolons are full stops. They end the sentence; you can add another sentence after one, before the period. But you can't add a subordinate clause, like _which can be a problem ..._ That has to be inside the sentence because it isn't a main clause. So a comma is what you need between them, not a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

You sure can, the relative clause introduced by *which* is supplementary and so allows a pause in prosody marked in writing by a comma or a semi-colon. However, it is more common to use a semi-colon when the parts of the sentence to the left and/or right of the semicolon have commas contained in them.

Some examples of this construction:

> Snakes are cold-blooded animals; which means that their body
>   temperature is about the same as the temperature of their
>   surroundings.(Zoology; A.M. Winchester, Harvey B. Lovell; D. Van
>   Nostrand Company, Inc. Princeton)
>
> Not into young Pierre, did there then steal that thought of utmost
>   sadness; pondering on the inevitable evanescence of all earthly
>   loveliness; which makes the sweetest things of life only food for
>   ever-devouring and omnivorous melancholy. (Pierre or, The
>   Ambiguities;  Herman Melville)
>
> Were there no such replies as these to Mr. Froude's reasons, there
>   would still be the reply furnished by his own interpretations of
>   history ; which make it clear that his denial must be understood as
>   but a qualified one. (On Social Evolution; Herbert Spencer; The
>   University of Chicago Press, Chicago, 1972)
>
> These little informal soviets elect a local soviet ; which elects
>   delegates to the city or country (community) soviet ; which elects
>   delegates to the government (State) soviet. ( The Nation: 10/4/1919,
>   Vol. 109 Issue 2831, p479-482, 4p)
>
> We have no idea what she looked like, for no portrait of her is known
>   to exist and not a single one of her contemporaries ever described her
>   physical appearance; which leads one to suspect that she was neither
>   beautiful nor ugly, but rather plain. (ACAD: History Today; The Lady and the Earl;
>   Greig, Martin; Sep2010, Vol. 60 Issue 9, p17-23, 7p, 9 Color
>   Photographs)
>
> People of quality do not work with their hands; which said, was
>   enough to put artists in their place. (ACAD: Art Bulletin; Dec93, Vol. 75 Issue 4, p583, 16p, 3bw)

Answer (score -1):

Semi-colons do prove to be difficult sometimes. In this case, though, it is a comma that should come before which.

Comment: This would be improved if you explained _why_ it's a comma in this case.